# Replacing Lithium batteries with larger ones

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lithium-polymer

I have some background with electronics, but that was in the "old days", so my knowledge of lithium battery types and charging processes is very limited.

I have a bunch of gadgets with one of those [baggie-type lithium batteries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytkWz.jpg). Some of them are size/weght restrained, but with a couple, size is no issue, so i was wondering if I could replace the provided battery with a (lot) larger ones. Those gadgets also have charging circuits (i've read the charging is voltage-controlled, so in theory, the capacity shouldn't matter for the charger, atleast in theory). All batteries are single-cell.

So, is this possible at all, and what should I be extra careful about, when selecting batteries (eg. when ordering cheap large ones from ebay), and what are the limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likley yes. 99.9 % of all lithium battery chargers are simple CC/CV chargers and they will just spend more time in their CC state until done. Others have built in ICs for management and some even have coulumb counters.

Is it just plus and minus comming out from the battery or are there more cables?

Comment: Plus and minus/red and black wire, same as on the picture. Cheap chinese electronics, which overpromise on lifetime/capacity. Will try resoldering one, and start charging it outside. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: If the battery is 7.4V like in the picture, that means it's a 2S battery, in other words it has two cells in series. Those should really be balance charged.

Comment: I put the picture just to show how it looks'. The actual battery is 3.7V type

Comment: I've resoldered one, and it's currently chargoing outside on the concrete (just to be safe). Will report if it works.

Comment: @Dampmaskin is correct. Any 2S battery pack is a different story but your 1S is far far simpler.

Comment: @Zgembo, Dude! Be careful solder to or near batteries. I once tried to convert a normal coin cell battery to a coin cell with solder legs myself. I almost lost my vision on both eyes and I still have one year less life expectancy from the shear shock itself. Long cables comming out of the battery - no problem. Very short or no cables - big hidden risk!

Comment: I have experience with those :) The batteries I have, all have ~5cm+ cables, just with different connectors (some directly soldered), so no problem with heat there.

Comment: Most likely NO. I mean, you may get away with up to 2x the size. But lithium chargers are matched to the battery, and good chargers will time out during charge if the battery does not reach its termination condition (current tapers to some low value) after some period. Also, many batteries have a third wire for a thermistor, and the charger will not work correctly unless the correct thermistor is attached (usually either 10k or 100k). But sounds like the cell in question has no thermistor.

Comment: @mkeith Which battery charger would this be? I've torn apart and built several and every one has been CC-CV with no timeout and hence no maximum capacity.

Comment: @Zgembo, any luck?

Comment: @winny, it is a basic safety feature of any good charger. I have designed around 5 or 6 products with built-in Lithium ion chargers. They all had timeouts. Review specs on lithium ion charger IC's. They all have timeouts. You cannot just float a lithium ion cell in CV mode indefinitely, so there has to be a timeout in case the battery never achieves its normal termination condition (based on current acceptance).

Comment: @mkeith Ah! A built in charger is a different story with far more things to worry about. I'm thinking about the manually plug in the charger in the wall and manually attach your battery to it.

Comment: @winny, how would you know if a charger you tore down had a timeout? The way I have tested my designs is by connecting the charger to a power supply that can sink current instead of a battery. I used a logging current meter to record charge current over time. After the timeout period, it shuts down. Generally the timeout is very generous because you don't want it to kick in under normal conditions.

Comment: @mkeith Either an integrated PWM with some external means to give it a crude current limit (sometimes actual output current sensing but also straight peak current cycle-by-cycle current limitation on the primary), but the PWM IC itself was made for running continuously and no external timers, or a full-fledged dual-OPamp with precise voltage and current regulation but still no timeout.

Comment: @winny yep, managed to recharge a (3x) larger one, seems to work fine :) Now it's recharginf (again) in a glass jar inside the house :)

Comment: @Zgembo Excellent! Your safe approach to ask first and try stuff which may, however unlikely, catch fire outside will hopefully pay off in the long run for you. Best of luck!